# Android Studio: Failed to create new activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I receive a nullpointer exception when I try to launch a new activity by clicking a button in the main activity. I did include the new activity in the manifest.xml.

This is the error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.toke.whistapp1/com.example.toke.whistapp1.EnterNames}: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
     at com.example.toke.whistapp1.EnterNames.<init>(EnterNames.java:15)
     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

UDDATE onCreate code:

```
package com.example.toke.whistapp1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EnterNames extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button submitButt;
private EditText play1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.play1);
private EditText play2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.play2);
private EditText play3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.play3);
private EditText play4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.play4);
private String[] names = new String[4];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_names);

}
```

XML code for new activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.toke.whistapp1.EnterNames">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Enter Player Names"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/play1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:hint="Player 1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/play2"
    android:hint="Player 2"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/play1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/play3"
    android:hint="Player 3"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/play2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/play4"
    android:hint="Player 4"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/play3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/subButt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/play4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post your onCreate code? 
I think you might be trying to get reference to a view object in an incorrect way. Just a suspicion at this point.

Comment: Do you have the layout for it? I think that is what's causing the NullPointerException

Comment: Layout for the new activity: 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: Hi @Toke,

I was meaning the new Activity which you're starting.

Can you post the code for "EnterNames" activity? If you can post the associated XML layout, that will help too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot look up views until after `setContentView(...)` is called in `onCreate(...)` when things are properly initialized.

Change your code to only declare the views:

```
private EditText play1;
private EditText play2;
private EditText play3;
private EditText play4;
```

and then assign the values in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_names);

    play1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.play1);
    play2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.play2);
    play3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.play3);
    play4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.play4);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just figured that excactly when you wrote :D